# Color management: Unable to change color temperature

Tags: windows, display, colors, temperature, amd-catalyst

I've recently bought a second display. Setting it up was easy, but the display has a certain yellowness to it that my other display does not, though it's not that much that it is completely unusable, seeing a clear white and a rather warm, with yellowish white adjacent to each other is quite jarring.

I've already had a problem like this once, but now I am unable to change the color temperature inside the catalyst control center as well as using the display color calibration tool supplied by Windows.
 Inside the catalyst control center there is no color temperature control panel the display whose temperature I would like to change while there is for my other display. Using the calibration tool leads to the change simply being almost instantly reverted after completion, even when I execute it as an admin.

I am really at the end of my rope and any help regarding how I can change color temperature and why I am currently unable to, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First off, it sounds like a simple monitor quality issue.  Perhaps your monitor is broken.  Did you buy the same monitor you had before?  The bulbs yellow over time (LEDs do not).  Next, you said the calibration tool settings revert... are you saying that you are able to get the adjustments you want via software?  The first thing I would do is tweak monitor settings on the monitor itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've recently bought it and it's a different model. To be exact its a new BenQ GW2760HS. I can get the settings that I would like , but then they simply go back to what they were. The monitor settings are for some reasons grayed out.

Comment: If you are doing a calibration, and it is immediately reverted - it probably is a setting in the Catalyst that reverts the Windows calibration (If I have understood your typing correctly).

Comment: `> The monitor settings are for some reasons grayed out.` - could be due to having an active monitor calibration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have color adjustments on the monitor; that is adjustment for R (Red) G (Green) and B (Blue):

Increasing only Blue will make the display less yellow - and inversely, more yellow if you decrease  ;-)
Decreasing Red **AND** Green **equal amount** will also pull down the yellow tone.

A `Kelvin` or `Color temperature` setting is simply a balancing adjustment for Red+Green versus Blue.

Comment: It sounds like he has that much figured out, but hasn't been able to get the settings to stick.

Answer (score -1):

Your monitor seems to have a lot of extra features. This might sound good, but aren't best to have accurate colors. Therefore, try deactivating all this special features (Film, Sport modes, senseye, etc.).

If this wont help, then you should consider calibrate your monitors with a hardware tool.

By the way, is your older monitor also LED?